# Regular expression is not working with verbose flag

Tags: python, regex

I have a pattern to search for

```
pat = re.compile(r'([\#-]?)(?:(?!\1)[\#-])?b')
```

but if I wanna to write this with verbose flag, then it stops working. Any idea?

```
pat = re.compile(r'''(
                     ([\#-]?)   # comment
                     (?:(?!\1)[\#-])? # comment
                      b)''', re.VERBOSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

You have extra parens surrounding the whole regexp in the verbose version. That changes the back-reference numbering, changing `\1` to `\2` in the verbose version should work.